# Passing from web application version to mobile version

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, mobile

If you developed a professional web application using the Java EE Architecture and technologies (Spring,hibernate...), that can have million of users and a very large database(Oracle).

And now you want to design and develop a mobile version of your web application ,How the mobile application can access to the business layer of the web version ;

I thought about web service ? What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty classic use case for a service layer on top of your business logic. Some things to keep in mind though:

1. Be careful not to write platform specific calls. For example, you might end up with a call like this: getNextArticle(String previousUrl). This would work well for the web, but not for a native mobile application. You'd need to refactor this call to make it work for both platforms.
2. Be careful to keep the size of your calls low. For the web it's ok to send back a payload of 300kb. (Or maybe it's not? Heh) For mobile you definitely don't want to send back 300kb for one call. You'll want to trim your return objects for mobile calls. Just something to think about.
3. Cache, cache, cache and then cache some more. Since you mentioned millions of users. =)